# Atmospheric correction using FLAASH

Tags: envi, atmospheric-correction, landsat-5, flaash

I want to run atmospheric correction on my Landsat TM5 picture using FLAASH (ENVI 4.8) but when I input radiance image (BIL format) into it, then this message is shown: "Enter ASCII filename containing wavelengths and FWHM" and when I enter metadata text file, it is not accepted.

I dont have wavelengths and FWHM in my metadata files which I have downloaded through USGS site.

Comment: 1) did you use MTL to open DN data before convert it to radiance? 2) why do not use Surface Reflectance product from USGS site?

Comment: Thank you for your answer
I solved that problem.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful.  - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/101182)